# order $a$ = 5, $a^3b = ba^3$. show that that $ab = ba$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $a, b$ be elements of a group $G$. Suppose that a has order $5$ and that $a^3b = ba^3$. I want to show that that $ab = ba$.

Here is what I think:

We know that we have $a^1, a^2, a^3, a^4, a^5 = 1$. So, $a^4 = a^{-1}$ and $a^3 = a^{-2}$ and $a^{2} = a^{-4}$. Now,

$a^3b = ba^3$ then $a^{-2}b = ba^{-2}$ then $ba^2 = a^2b$ then $ba^{-4} = a^{-4}b$ then $a^{-1}b = ba^{-1}$ then multiply on the left and right by $a$ to get $ba=ab$. Is this correct or is there a simpler approach?

Comment: I don't see how you go from $a^{-2}b = ba^{-2}$ to $ba^2 = a^2b$.

Comment: multiply on left and right by $a^2$

Comment: ok but then it would be easier to understand if only multiply on one side by step. Furthemore the step $a^{-2}b=ba^{-2}$ is useless.

Answer (score 6):

Since $a$ has order 5, we have $a = a^6$. Then:
$$ ab = a^6b = a^3(a^3b) = a^3(ba^3) = (a^3b)a^3 = (ba^3)a^3 = ba^6 = ba \;\;\;\;\square $$

Comment: Do we need to know G is abelian for this?

Comment: @PhilKing - No, why? That is the whole point, we don't know the group is abelian (if we did, the problem would have no content). I didn't use commutativity, I only used associativity, which holds in all groups, and the hypothesis that $a^3b = ba^3$.

Answer (score 5):

The point is that since the exponent $3$ is coprime to the order $5$ of $a$, the orders of $a$ and $a^{3}$ are the same, and thus so are the subgroups generated by each one. Therefore the centralizer of $b$, which contains $a^{3}$, also contains $a$.

Comment: Translating Andrea's solution into lower-level (or is it upper-level?) language: if $x$ and $y$ commute, then so do any power of $x$ and any power of $y$ (for example, that can be proved by induction, in a way very similar to mathguy's solution). Now $a = a^6$ (something like this could always be done when "3" in the hypothesis and "5" as the order are relatively prime), and $a^6$ is a power of $a^3$; since $a^3$ and $b$ commute, so do $a^6$ and $b$.

Answer (score 2):

$b=a^2a^3b=a^2ba^3=a^{-1}a^3ba^3=a^{-1}ba^3a^3=a^{-1}ba$. So you have you result.